# Mysterious => There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I know there are million Posts on this exception here but I don't Understand this one here. 
I have an extrem simple example pipe Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISRARiskExport
{ 
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void RiskExport(long sraid, long revID, string JobID);
}
```

And when I call it ones everything is fine but when two clients call it at the same time it throws this exception. 
The Server direktly setup a new thread and returns to the client.

```
public void RiskExport(long sraid, long revID, string JobID)
{
ThreadStarter starter = new ThreadStarter(new ThreadStartWithParameter(RunExportJob), new SRAInfo() { sraid = sraid, revID = revID, JobID = JobID });
Thread t = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(starter.ThreadStartEntry));
t.IsBackground = true;
t.Start();
}
```

So therefor it can’t be a timeout problem, because it takes les then 1 sec from cleint to server and back. Especially when I call it synchronously in for loop from my unit test

```
string JobID = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
string baseAddress = "net.pipe://localhost/SRADocumentService";
ChannelFactory<ISRARiskExport> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISRARiskExport>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
ISRARiskExport svc = factory.CreateChannel();
JobID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
svc.RiskExport(sraid, revID, JobID);
}
```

I all ready activated the WCF trace. Here I can see that the Exception Is thrown by each call. The Detail pane doesn’t help me at all, because it one shows me the Exception twice =>
There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).

[image]

With different Stack traces =>

[image]

[image]

I also see in the Debugview that the Exceptions come long after the call is back at the client.
My Questions are:

1. Why is the Service working as expectet even when it is throwing this Exception
2. How can I get rid of the Exception because they all get to the log file and I’m not abel to catch it.

THX Michael

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this same sequence exceptions with very similar trace data, and after changing the binding to the following the exceptions stopped. Note i have no idea what the implications of these changes are, so use with caution.

```
    public Binding GetBinding()
    {
        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding
        {
            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            MaxConnections = 200,
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
            TransactionFlow = false,
            TransactionProtocol = TransactionProtocol.WSAtomicTransaction11,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.StreamedRequest,
            HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.WeakWildcard
        };
        binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
        return binding;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

We've seen such behavior due to how named pipes pooling is implemented internally in WCF. In our case such exceptions were in logs more or less randomly (not after each call), but after studying MS reference sources we decided that they are unavoidable. And you mentioned "Exceptions come long after the call is back at the client" which makes me thinking that you're observing the same behavior.

You can see "proof" of that [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.servicemodel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/TransportDefaults.cs,1401d08e6b739137): `NamedPipeConnectionPoolSettings` has `IdleTimeout` set to some default, which equals [2 minutes](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.servicemodel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/TransportDefaults.cs,1401d08e6b739137).

Maybe we were wrong in our decision that this is unavoidable because I now see that `NamedPipeConnectionPoolSettings` class is public and `IdleTimeout` property is also public and can be set to `TimeSpan.MaxValue` which should prevent closing of pipes and these exceptions.

Hope this helps.